# How to remove the trailing comma from a loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code so far:

```
def main():
    for var in range (1, 101):
        num= IsPrime(var)
        if num == 'true':
             print(var, end=', ')
```

The IsPrime function calculates whether or not a function is prime.

I need to print out the prime numbers from 1 to 100 formatted into a single line with commas and spaces in between. for example, output should look like:

```
2,  3,  5,  7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,  41,  43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71,  73,  79,  83,  89,  97
```

I tried to run my program, but I always get a trailing comma at the end of 97. I don't know how to remove the comma, and because it is a loop, str.rstrip  and [:-1] don't work.

I need to use a loop and I can't use

```
print('2') 
print(', ', var, end='')
```

for the other prime numbers.

I can't tell if there's an easier way to code this or I'm not aware of a function that can do this correctly.

Comment: `IsPrime(var)` should be returning a boolean not a string then if `IsPrime(var)` would be sufficient to check

Answer (score 10):

The idiomatic Python code in my opinion would look something like this:

```
print(', '.join([str(x) for x in xrange(1, 101) if IsPrime(x) == 'true']))
```

(Things would be better if `IsPrime` actually returned `True` or `False` instead of a string)

This is functional instead of imperative code.

If you want imperative code, you should print the `', '` before each element excepting the first item of the loop. You can do this with a boolean variable which you set to true after you've seen one item.

Comment: Would be even more pythonic, if you deleted the `[ ... ]` around the expression. Then it would just be a light-weight generator that is passed to the `join`-method...

Comment: @koffein Not bad at all! I like `filter` myself, as it works in pretty much any functional programming language.

Comment: Well, in this case `ifilter` from `itertools` would be a function to consider, because as far as I know `filter` returns a list, just like the list comprehension with `[ ... ]` up there.
I personally do not like filter, if I have to create a `lambda` inline. I a function already exists, its fine, but otherwise it looks more crowded to me then the list-comprehension/generator...

Comment: @koffein, that would actually be worse as python then still has to build a list for join.

Comment: Am I wrong when I say that `print(', '.join([x for x in xrange(1, 101) if IsPrime(x) == 'true']))` fails at all, as join() expects a string but gets an int? So it misses an `str(x)`, doesn't it?

Comment: @mstuebner Right you are. Corrected. I knew there was a reason I intuitively wrote the list comprehension first.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I did some timing of generators vs. lists... You are right, from the time perspective it is better to create a list. I just do not get how a more "lazy-evaluation"-type of implementation can be slower.

Comment: @koffein, because internally python has to create a list if you pass a generator as it has to do two passes over the data so it actually adds more overhead

Answer (score 5):

You can put all the numbers into a list and then join all the values:

```
def main():
    primes = []
    for var in range (1, 101):
        if IsPrime(var) == 'true':
            primes.append(var)
        num = IsPrime(var)
    print(', '.join(primes))
```