# I have unwanted commas at the end of every column in my output cvs file.. How can I remove them?

Tags: python, csv

```
with open('resultsVT.csv', 'wb') as c:                                                                                                                                                 
        for row in fileV:                                                                                                                                                                  
            for item in row:                                                                                                                                                               
               c.write(item + ",")                                                                                                                                                        
            c.write('\n')
```

what I'm seeing

```
aaaa,bbbb,ccc,
zzz,eee,ffff,
ccc,ddd,gggg,
```

what I want

```
aaaa,bbbb,ccc
zzz,eee,ffff
ccc,ddd,gggg
```

Comment: Don't write CSV files by hand, `import csv`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the trailing comma from a loop in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505452/how-to-remove-the-trailing-comma-from-a-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

Your loop adds a comma after each element, no wonder why you get an extra comma in the end.

Quick alternative:

```
c.write(",".join(row))
```

Better alternative: the `csv` module and the super-fast writerows that seem to match your data exactly (list of lists)

```
with open('resultsVT.csv', 'wb') as c:  # wb for Python 2, ,newline='' for python 3
   cw = csv.writer(c)
   cw.writerows(fileV)
```

Comment: @jean-Francis Fabre I used the alternative method you posted and it worked pretty well. in python 2 ( c.write(",".join(row)) joins the rows overtime it runs through the script so I wouldn't recommend using that.

Comment: the second method is definitely the best one. The first method still needs linefeed output.